# How to keep textures distorted

Tags: javascript, webgl

I am a novice in webgl. I have written an effect of distorting the texture with the mouse.

I want to keep the distorted texture and not let the texture return to its original appearance.

My idea is to use FBO or copyteximage2d, but the implementation When it fails, it may be wrong in writing or thinking, how do I write to make it happen. Thanks in advance!

```
attribute vec2 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;

uniform vec2 u_resolution;

varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {
  vec2 zeroToOne = a_position / u_resolution;

  vec2 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0;

  vec2 clipSpace = zeroToTwo - 1.0;

  gl_Position = vec4(clipSpace * vec2(1, -1), 0, 1);

  v_texCoord = a_texCoord;
}
```

```
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D u_image;
uniform vec2 u_mouse;

varying vec2 v_texCoord;


vec2 pinch(vec2 vector) 
  { 
     vec2 center = u_mouse + vector;
     float dist = distance(v_texCoord, u_mouse);

     vec2 point = u_mouse + smoothstep(0., 1., dist / 0.1) * vector;
     return (v_texCoord - center) + point;
  }

void main() {
  vec2 vector = vec2(0.035, 0.035);

  vec2 tex = pinch(vector);

  gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_image, tex);
}
```

```js
var image = new Image();
function main() {
  image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
  image.src = "https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod/images/face-wash-gettyimages-489974588-1557345669.jpg";
  image.onload = function() {
    render(image);
  }
}

main();

function shaderSourceById(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id).textContent;
}

function shader(glContext, type, source) {
  const shader = glContext.createShader(type);
  
  glContext.shaderSource(shader, source);
  glContext.compileShader(shader);

  if (!glContext.getShaderParameter(shader, glContext.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
      throw 'err' + glContext.getShaderInfoLog(shader);
  }

  return shader;
}

function installProgram(glContext, vertexSource, fragSource) {
  const vertexShader = shader(glContext, glContext.VERTEX_SHADER, vertexSource);
  const fragShader = shader(glContext, glContext.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragSource);

  const prog = glContext.createProgram();

  glContext.attachShader(prog, vertexShader);
  glContext.attachShader(prog, fragShader);
  glContext.linkProgram(prog);

  if (!glContext.getProgramParameter(prog, glContext.LINK_STATUS)) {
      throw 'err' + glContext.getProgramInfoLog(prog);
  }

  glContext.useProgram(prog);
  return prog;
}

function getGLContext(glCanvas) {
  glCanvas.width = glCanvas.clientWidth;
  glCanvas.height = glCanvas.clientHeight;

  const gl = glCanvas.getContext('webgl');
  if (!gl) {
      throw 'Browser not supported';
  }

  gl.clearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  return gl;
}

const gl = getGLContext(document.getElementById('glCanvas'), {preserveDrawingBuffer: true});

const prog = installProgram(gl,
    shaderSourceById('vertex-shader'),    
    shaderSourceById('fragment-shader')
);


var mouseLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(prog, "u_mouse");

function render(image) {
  var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(prog, "a_position");
  var resolutionLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(prog, "u_resolution");
  var texCoordLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(prog, "a_texCoord");


  var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  setRectangle(gl, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);

  gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  gl.uniform2f(resolutionLocation, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

  var texCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texCoordBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
      0.0,  0.0,
      1.0,  0.0,
      0.0,  1.0,
      0.0,  1.0,
      1.0,  0.0,
      1.0,  1.0,]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texCoordLocation);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(texCoordLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  var texture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
  const fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(
    gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);
        var result = gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER);
        
        if (result != gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
            alert("unsupported framebuffer");
            return;
        }
 
  var newTex = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, newTex);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE); // 4
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

  gl.copyTexImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 0, 0, image.width, image.height, 0);

  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);

  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
}

function setRectangle(gl, x, y, width, height) {
  var x1 = x;
  var x2 = x + width;
  var y1 = y;
  var y2 = y + height;
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
     x1, y1,
     x2, y1,
     x1, y2,
     x1, y2,
     x2, y1,
     x2, y2,
  ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}


document.getElementById('glCanvas').addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  let x = e.x / image.width;
  let y = e.y / image.height;
  
  gl.uniform2f(mouseLocation, x, y);
  
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
});
```

Comment: Both approaches are feasible, [just do it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/copyTexImage2D) ?

Comment: @LJᛃ I build the FBO first, then write copyTexImage2D.

Comment: Check out [this tutorial](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-image-processing-continued.html)